# Practical Applications of Information Algebras

Tags: it.information-theory

I've started reading [Information Algebras, Kohlas](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-0009-6) (the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_algebra) may give you the gist) and I am curious as to whether any ideas from this theory/book could be practically implemented, perhaps as some sort of knowledge representation and querying library/toolkit. In chapter 2, he mentions that

> "The complexity of computation for the operations of combination and marginalization as well as the memory space tends to increase exponentially with the size of the domains of the valuations".

However, chapter 4 discusses some techniques/conditions (*local computation*) which reduce these domains to make computation more feasible.

My question is:

(a) Has anyone implemented this framework in any capacity

(b) If not, would it be possible?

By "implement", I imagine a tool/language where the user can input a knowledge graph and all the variables/domains followed by observations of these variables. Then the user can "query" this system about particular valuations or sets of valuations.

I understand that the point of this research area is largely to unify various theoretical areas (probability theory, Bayesian networks, etc...), but turning these theoretical ideas into code is often very rewarding.